# Strong From Good Nutrition

Tags: meaning, prepositions, usage, antonyms

Definition 11 for "*from*" in [this dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/from) has this example:

> They were ***weak from hunger***.

Does that mean that I could write:

They were ***strong from good nutrition***.

?

Comment: They're not really equivalent usages. Children *grow to be strong* if they have good nutrition over many years - it's not a temporary thing like being "weak from hunger" because you haven't eaten for hours.

Comment: No, there's no parallel construction with *strong*.

Comment: What @snailboat said. Temporary lack of food can reasonably be said to make you weak. But in general, ***strong*** is too strong a word to describe any (again, temporary) result of short-term eating activity. Except perhaps where that activity is specifically *starting to eat again, and thereby regaining strength lost during preceding starvation*. Mostly the short-term result of hearty eating is *torpor*, not *vigour*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  How about "*they felt better* ***from*** *a good meal*"?

Comment: @meatie: Perhaps it's a cultural rather than a language thing. Because native Anglophones tend not to think in terms of a person's default state being "weak from lack of food", they're not likely to think of "having a good meal" as *strengthening*. Consequently, we're not likely to use ***from*** because it strongly implies the *purpose* of the good meal was to gain strength (or "feel better"). You're much more likely to hear *"they felt better **after** a good meal"*, which "weakens" the causal relationship aspect somewhat.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So, in the pattern "*[adjective]* ***from*** *[something]*", the causation should be unintended?

Comment: @meatie: No. I'm trying to explain my native speaker "gut feel" as to why *to feel better / be strong **from** [some antecedent cause / activity]* is not a common form, but obviously I'm not doing a very good job of it. Maybe another way to address it is simply to say *"[adjective] **from** [something]"* (where ***from = because of***) is a relatively unusual form that you probably shouldn't try to extend into constructions you haven't already seen in regular use. I'd also say it's mainly restricted to contexts where *adjective* is "negative/undesirable".

Comment: As it says here, [*Certain adjectives are often followed by a particular preposition*](http://www.fe.hku.hk/telec/pgram/5-gr/535f/535-014.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's perfectly fine but sounds like rhetorical prose, meaning something someone would say in a speech or a declaration, rather then casual speech.

> eat right -or- ate right

is an easier way to express this.

Comment: So, "*strong* ***from*** *good nutrition*" is poorly written compared to "*weak* ***from*** *hunger*"?

Comment: I said it's perfectly fine just a bit over expressive for casual conversation.  It's something you would more use in a speech or declaration.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with it grammatically. It just happens that English speakers don't use this as often as "weak from hunger".

You might try "...strong, due to good nutrition..."